# Automatic resize two windows to fit desktop

Tags: windows, desktop

I have a single monitor, but with a wide resolution. Some times it would be helpful to have two applications running next to each other. Is there a tool to quickly tell windows to resize the two applications to fit the desktop? Perhaps even with an option to make the one application use 75% and the other 25%

I know the Windows 7 Alt+left/right arrow feature, which is nice, but still needs too many clicks.

Answer (score 9):

With Windows 7 you can just pull the windows to the left or right edge of the screen. One click :P

Comment: It's called "Snap" http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/snap

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on the 2 edges between my 2 monitors. Works far left and far right but not on the left of the right hand monitor and not on the right of my left hand monitor.

Comment: Oh yeah, it seems to not work "in between". Sadly. @MarkRobinson: Everything has to have a name it seems...

Comment: @Shevek Now I know better: Use WINDOWS+LEFT/RIGHT to snap the window currently in the foreground to various places.

Answer (score 7):

1. Click the first window, then hit <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>.
2. Then, click the second window (on the same monitor) and hit <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>Right arrow</kbd>.

Comment: Great! One of the best fitting answers here...

Answer (score 3):

You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click each of the windows on the task bar then right click and select `Tile Vertically`

Comment: it does not function with windows 7, but with windows xp

Answer (score 0):

Minimize all windows and restore only the two that you want to tile. Then right click on taskbar and choose one arrangement you want (tile vertically, horizontally, cascade...).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Windows window manipulation keyboard shortcut, but be prepared to play Twister with your fingers. ;-)

Hold WINDOWS + CONTROL + SHIFT and tap one of the ARROW keys. This will move the active window to either the left or right side, hide the window, or full-screen toggle it.

You may need to click the window first to make it the active one for the shortcut to work.